# I can't add principled BSDF textures in Blender 4.0

Tags: texturing, materials

So I'm currently trying to add some materials to my plane, as show below:
[image]

But there's a problem with the materials tab. First, the "New" and "Open" options aren't shown beneath the "Surface" tab. So I tried opening the Shading tab and was advised to select Principled BSDF and then press CTRL + SHIFT + T (or in the case of my macbook: CMD + SHIFT + T), but nothing happened. Most forum questions regarding this issue are from Blender 2.9, not the current 4.0 .

What can I do to add textures to my plane?

Comment: Do you have the Node Wrangler addon enabled in Preferences > Addons? - Those shortcuts are provided by that addon. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/addons/node/node_wrangler.html?utm_source=blender-3.6.5#node-wrangler. Also you've already got a material (Material.001) on the plane so you won't see a New button unless you add another material and you won't see an Open button unless you've selected a shader that requires a file input.